# faster imread with matlab for images with small portion of data

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I'm trying to track objects in separated frames of a video. If I do a background subtraction before storing the images the size of the images will be much smaller (like one fifth). so I was wondering if I can also read these images faster since most of the pixels are zero. Still simple imread didn't make any difference.

I also tried the pixelregion option for loading only the location of objects and that didn't work either since there are like ten objects in each frame.

Comment: Perhaps you can get a speedup by either calling it 10 times with a very small set of points, or by calling it once for only the columns and rows that span your 10 objects.

Comment: PixelRegion is supported only for a few formats, what is the format you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be faster to store the frames as a video file, rather than individual images. Then you can read them using `vision.VideoFileReader` from the Computer Vision System Toolbox.